# TChromium OnClick

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I want to track how many clicks the user did inside TChromium. I don't care if he clicks in a "white space"/link/button/image/etc.. I just want to know how many clicks he did. I was hoping there is Onclick event in TChromium but there is none.  How can I know if the user clicks?

Comment: This is again upon document. I'll be right back...

Comment: I believe you need to hook the mouse buttons. Otherwise I don't see why TChromium would care if you click in a area where nothing needs to happen.

Comment: @RBA, I'm afraid you're right, because I don't think you'll be able to listen clicks into containers like Flash in JavaScript.

Comment: Btw, what version of Chromium are you using?

Comment: Im using cef3..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an event listener. The problem here is that CEF3 doesn't support DOM event listeners like CEF1 did, so it's not that easy there (not impossible though). One quite dirty workaround before I try to craft a V8 interaction example can be this. You create a unique enough string, add an event listener for the whole document, and in this event you log the message with that unique string. And in Delphi you'll be waiting for that unique log message, e.g.:

```
const
  MyClickMessage = '08B52B44-748F-44BB-AC6C-5179D6C1F523';

procedure TForm1.Chromium1LoadEnd(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame; httpStatusCode: Integer);
begin
  if frame.IsMain then
    frame.ExecuteJavaScript(
      'document.addEventListener("click", function(evnt){' +
          'console.log("' + MyClickMessage + '");' +
      '});',
      '',
      0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1ConsoleMessage(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const message, source: ustring; line: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if message = MyClickMessage then
  begin
    Result := True;
    ShowMessage('User clicked!');
  end;
end;
```

Hacky, right :)? I'll try to come up with something better (using V8 engine)..

Comment: Will this work when user is making a click on the webpage on a non 'responsive'(href,button,image,etc) area?

Comment: @RBA, should. But in my code, I'm binding events only to the the main frame and not preventing bubbling. That's no good.

Comment: @RBA, if you can do JavaScript, I can provide you V8 implementation. I just don't know how to make a global click hook for the whole document (stop event bubbling and keep the original functionality). I'm no good at JavaScript.